# How to Enable CORS for Credentials and Preflight in Node/Express

Tags: node.js, express, cors, fetch

I know, there are a billion CORS questions on here. I have gone through dozens. I'm still not sure what the issue is, and I think I understand CORS decently well, but obviously I'm missing something here.

I'm trying to get my (Node/Express) API running on a real URL (i.e. deployed, not using `origin: "*"`), and tell the browser to actually fulfill requests from my GUI's URL.

For some routes, I need authentication, so I need to add `credentials` in there.

This is a pretty standard use case, but maybe something changed with the API since I last did this or maybe I just forgot, but regardless I can't seem to get this working and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

There seem to be several ways to go about enabling CORS for all requests in my Express app. I'm currently using the `cors` middleware with its options object.

Specifically, here's the code I'm using.

```
const app: express.Application = express();

const corsOptions = {
  credentials: true,
  origin: 'https://my-gui.example.com',
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
  preflightContinue: true,
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

What am I doing wrong? When I make a `fetch` request from my browser, I receive the below error.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://my-api.example.com/graphql' from origin 'https://my-gui.example.com'
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an
opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource
with CORS disabled.
```

If I add `app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));` before the `app.use` call (why I would need this when I specified `OPTIONS` in the `method` list, I don't know), I get a different error (which leads me to believe I do need this for some reason).

```
Access to fetch at 'https://my-api.example.com/graphql' from origin 'https://my-gui.example.com'
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying to access this website `https://my-api.example.com/graphql` but the shared snip looks like you gave an access only to `https://my-gui.example.com` and this is different from above one.

So my answer is please change your snippet like below,

```
const corsOptions = {
  credentials: true,
  origin: "*",
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
  preflightContinue: true,
}
```

(or) try

```
const corsOptions = {
      credentials: true,
      origin: ['https://my-gui.example.com','https://my-api.example.com/graphql'],
      methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
      preflightContinue: true,
    }
```

Comment: 1. I am trying to access `https://my-api.example.com/graphql` from `https://my-gui.example.com`.

2. CORS origins ignore the path (and query parameters), so `/graphql` isn't necessary.

3. Again, I am not trying to allow `"*"`, I want this to be secure and whitelist the actual domain from which the request is originating.

4. Just to be sure, I tested out the suggested code and it does not work (I still receive `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`).